# Use JavaScript to prevent spacebar?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a live search on a site I'm developing. At the moment, it searches the MySql database after the first character is typed, and updates the search for each new character. When <kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed as the first character, it displays all entries in the database. I don't want it to do that. I have the following code that I found somewhere that prevents the `SPACE` character from being typed:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e){
  var ignore_key_codes = [8,32];
  if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, ignore_key_codes) >= 0){
  e.preventDefault();
 }
});
```

This does what it's meant to do, but not exactly what I want. This will prevent the space bar from working in the text input at all, what I require is that it only prevents the space bar if it's the first character being typed. For example, typing " apples" would prevent the space, but typing "apples oranges" wouldn't.

Is there anything I can try to achieve this?

Comment: Do a specific check for the spacebar and the length of the textbox's current value being zero.

Comment: Instead of using JavaScript to inhibit your users from using the spacebar, you need to change your search algorithm to take into account spaces and not do a full search when they are entered. Disabling the spacebar, even in this particular case, will really frustrate your users.

Comment: Maybe you can use `trim()` in your PHP code.

Comment: Remember someone could just paste in a space character.

Comment: Using trim in my PHP won't work because the count for each space is done by JavaScript, client side, removing spaces server side will still display all results, won't it?

Comment: Note that this is a server side bug. you should fix it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32 && $.trim($(this).val()) == ''){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        alert("searching..");
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/JJG9M/

Comment: Thank you. This worked well. I didn't require the else statement though. Also, thank you to everyone else for your input.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily like this example:

```
function keyPress(e) { 
    var e = window.event || e;
    var key = e.keyCode;
    //space pressed
    if (key == 32) { //space
        return;
    }
    searchInDataBase(); //make your ajax call to search in data base etc.
}
```

If the `space` key is pressed, you return and dont do nothing, otherwise you continue in your search...

Comment: +1. with e.preventDefault() you are suppressing the space bar default action.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @Florent's comment, when a user types a value into your textbox,check if the trimmed value is != '' if so it should be safe to continue

e.g

```
if($.trim($txtbox.val()) != ''){ // proceed to do search

}
```